# as3 runtime error:. text=unavailable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, android-camera, runtime-error

I am attempting to call the cameraUi method using adobe air in flash pro. i am trying to call the `loggedIn();` method from the document class (main.as) but am getting the following runtime error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled error:. text=unavailable
```

I have tried have tried commenting out different pieces of the code but cant locate the problem area. bellow is my AccessCamera Class.

```
package Classes {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.media.*;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.CameraUI;
    import flash.events.MediaEvent;
    import flash.net.*;

    public class AccessCamera extends MovieClip {
    //-------------- CameraUI-----------------------//
        public static var ui = new CameraUI();
        public static var video = new Video();
        //------------- end Camera UI------------------//

        public function AccessCamera() {
            // constructor code
            trace ("access camera class accessed");
            loggedIn();
        }

        public function loggedIn(){         
            //------------cmaera UI---------------//
            ui.launch(MediaType.VIDEO);
            ui.addEventListener(MediaEvent.COMPLETE,UICompleteHandler);
        }
        public function UICompleteHandler(event:MediaEvent):void{
            var media:MediaPromise = event.data;
            trace(media.file.url  + " - " + media.relativePath + " - " +media.mediaType);
            parent.addChild(video);
            var conn:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
            conn.connect(null);
            //attach a stream  to the video-object
            var stream:NetStream = new NetStream(conn);
            video.attachNetStream(stream);
            stream.client = new MobileClient();
            //play the stream
            stream.play(media.file.url);
        }
    }
}
class MobileClient {
    public function onMetaData(info:Object):void {
    trace("metadata: duration=" + info.duration + " width=" + info.width + " height=" + info.height + " framerate=" + info.framerate);
    }
    public function onCuePoint(info:Object):void {
        trace("cuepoint: time=" + info.time + " name=" + info.name + " type=" + info.type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error can be caused by a few things:

1. There is no camera access. Unless you are on a mobile device (you do not say if the error is coming from a mobile device or from testing on desktop), `CameraUI` is not supported. You should **always** check [`CameraUI.isSupported`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraUI.html#isSupported) before trying to use the class
2. The camera is already in use, in which case there is nothing you can do about it
3. The app is in the background when the `launch()` method is called

You can listen for `ErrorEvent.ERROR` on the `CameraUI` object in order to catch this specific error. There might be more details available in the event object it passes.

Comment: Thanks I was testing on my pc which dosnt support cameraUi. I am now getting an err on the device when app is installed `unfortunatly, Gallery has stopped` when i launch the app. however this is proberbly another question.